# Exclude results from Google Search where keywords are in link titles instead of content

Tags: google-search

How can I make Google search exclude link titles from showing up as matching when I want the keywords to match on page content?

For example, I want to find out how I can use the Kendo UI grid component in conjunction with self referencing hiearchical data.

So I do this query:

> "kendo ui" grid "self referencing"

which on the surface seems OK.

However, the [majority of the results](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22kendo+ui%22+grid+%22self+referencing%22+&oq=%22kendo+ui%22+grid+%22self+referencing%22), including [the first one](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/self-referencing-hierarchy-grid-expand-all.aspx), doesn't address this at all.

What they do have is outbound links named "Kendo UI", which is of no interest to me.
I want the *content* to have the phrase "Kendo UI" (which neither of the results have).

An imaginary functionality would be something like:
`+content:"kendo ui" grid "self referencing"`
or perhaps:
`"kendo ui" grid "self referencing" -a:"kendo ui"`
(for excluding anchor tags with that title)

How can I perform a search with this requirement and exclude certain link titles?

Comment: Congratulations, now _this page_ appears as the top two results for the above search query! :) By why two results for the same page?!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `intext:` or `inanchor:` operators. I think `-inanchor:kendo` is what you're looking for, but `intext:kendo`may help, too. Or try `-allinanchor:kendo ui`.

Here's a good list of search operators: http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html.